# Read cell position and set value with particular position from excel file using java

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, apache-poi

I am using a excel file into my project. there is some header and input field ,i want get that particular cell position and set the value on input field through database table using java.
[image]
This is excel screen .

Comment: Please provide you effort and post if you have any problem in it. apache poi gives enough api to do that

Comment: Good luck! You've already tagged your question with apache-poi. You'll find plenty of examples on how to solve your problem on SO.

Comment: you can use Apache POI API to achieve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have [apache-poi](https://poi.apache.org/) a very good API that can be handy in manipulating the Microsoft documents.
Here is the code snippet

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        FileInputStream fsIP= new FileInputStream(new File("path to your excel file"));
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fsIP);
        HSSFSheet worksheet = wb.getSheetAt(0); 
        Cell cell = null;
        cell = worksheet.getRow(2).getCell(2);//get the row and cell value from db
        cell.setCellValue("update the value in excel");                  
        fsIP.close();
        FileOutputStream output_file =new FileOutputStream(new File("path to your excel file"));
        wb.write(output_file);
        output_file.close();
    }
```

Comment: can u explain full example of related topic

Comment: @sattuvirus so basically you need to fetch the row and column from db which you would like to update in your excel sheet. then using the above function you need to open the file using InputStream and then you need to create the HSSFWorkbook object. It is basically top level object for creating the new sheet. And then you get the rows and cell using getRows() and getCell() to update the value. then you set the value and out stream basically writes the value to your excel file.

Comment: @sattuvirus please consider accepting the solution in case if i helped you in anyway.

Comment: I cannot understand process

Comment: @sattuvirus You are trying to update some certain rows and columns in your excel. You can get the rows by using additional count variable and to get the column you can assign a column separately like let's say you have id-column 1, name- column 2, age- column 3 so 1, 2 and 3 are your columns now using the above code you can pass the rows and column and set your updated data.

Comment: @sattuvirus please consider accepting the solution in case if i helped you in anyway.

Comment: i write a java code which is stored static array value into excel file but i want to store database value into excel file can u help me i will show you code

Comment: @sattuvirus Great now you need to make one connection with your database and fetch the value and then write those values into your excel file. Try yourself this one if you face any problem you can raise an issue on SO. Meanwhile consider accepting the solution in case if you think it is helpful.